# Angular custom Form Validator use other Controlers

Tags: angular

I try to implement a custom Validator for my Angular 9 Form. The validation is a little bit difficult.

Because a couple of fields depends on the selection of a select input.

For example if I select option one of my select, Formfield 3 is required.

But if I select option two, Formfield 5 is required.

That's why I have writte a custom Validator:

```
export class FormComponent {
  public form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    ...
    selectField: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
    ...
    formField3: new FormControl(null, [this.validatorArtAende]),
    formField4: new FormControl(),
    formField5: new FormControl(null, [this.validatorArtAender])
  });

  validator (control: AbstractControl) => {
    if (this.form.value.selectField === 'option1' && control.value.length === 0) {
      return { required: true };
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

The issue is that this.form is unknwon (Cannot read property 'form' of undefined).
So is there any option to pass the form or the value of a diffrent Control to the custom validator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, [AbstractControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#parent) has a `Parent` property. You should be able to use that to traverse to your parent `FormGroup` and then to the `selectField` inside your validator.

```
validator (control: AbstractControl) => {
  if (control.parent && control.parent.controls['selectField'] === 'option1' && control.value.length === 0) {
    return { required: true };
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: I still run in the same error. But I added an if around your if, by which i validate if control.parent already exist (if (control.parent) {...} return null). Thank you for your support. I would like to accept your answer when you adjust your code

Comment: Updated to make sure the validator checks for a parent before trying to access it.

Comment: Rememeber that you need check the controls also when change the `selectField`. For this you can use some like hte `checkControls validator` in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77372335/angular-reactive-form-specify-when-to-validate/77373947#77373947) or subscribe to valueChange or use `(input)` event and use [updateValueAndValidity()](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity)

Answer (score 1):

Just to update this question as I assume things have moved on in the Angular world as I needed to achieve this very same thing today. You can access all other controls within the form directly from control passed into the validator function using: -

```
const compareControl = control.get(controlName);
```

I found using the control.parent approach caused numerous issues with typing and also added additional complexity which is not required.