# Angular Custom Validation Control doesn't get form value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

This code in my *form-validators.ts*:

```
console.log('password:', password?.value);
console.log('confirmPwd:', confirmPwd?.value);
```

always fetched me `undefined`, causing the custom validation (`matchPwdValidator()`) to constantly return `false`. If I fetched *confirmPwd* in the switch, it will print out the correct details. Below is a summarized version of my codes.

form-validators.ts

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

export class FormValidators {
  ...

  static matchPwdValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
      const password = control.get("password");
      const confirmPwd = control.get("confirmPwd");
  
      console.log('password:', password?.value);
      console.log('confirmPwd:', confirmPwd?.value);
  
      if (!password || !confirmPwd || password.value !== confirmPwd.value) {
        return { PwdNotMatched: true };
      }
  
      return null;
    };
  }
}
```

form.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import { FormValidators } from "../utilities/form-validators";

@Component({
  selector: "app-form",
  templateUrl: "./form.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./form.component.scss"],
})
export class FormComponent {
  
  cpwdError: boolean = false;

  sampleForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    
    this.sampleForm= this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        ...
        password: ["", FormValidators.passwordValidator()],
        confirmPwd: ["", FormValidators.matchPwdValidator()],
      },
    );
    
    ...
    this.sampleForm.get('confirmPwd')?.statusChanges .subscribe(() => {
      this.updateErrorFlags('confirmPwd');
    });
  }


  private updateErrorFlags(controlName: string): void {
    const control = this.sampleForm.get(controlName);
    if (control) {
      switch (controlName) {
        ...
        case 'confirmPwd':
          this.cpwdError = control.hasError('PwdNotMatched') && control.dirty;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: try `control.parent?.get()` inplace of `control.get("");`

Comment: Thank you, changing to `control.parent?.get()` fixed the problem. May I know why `control.get("")` doesn't work?

Comment: A Validator can be "attached" to a FormControl or to a FormGroup (or to a FormArray). In your case, your validator is "attached" to a control (the formControl "confirmPwd"). control.parent is the formGroup "sampleForm".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are set the `matchPwdValidator` validation to the "confirmPwd" FormControl. It can't find any control with name: "password" and "confirmPwd". You should get both controls from the root form group of the current form control.

```
const password = control.parent?.get('password');
const confirmPwd = control.parent?.get('confirmPwd');
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-6u8pkn?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Thank you, changing to your given answer works like a charm. However I still don't understand why it doesn't work with `control.get("")`. Is it because my `matchPwdValidator()` is not in _form.component.ts_ where I declare my FormGroup? Sorry if I am slow.

Comment: See that Angular not "validate automatically" an input if you don't use setValue or change the input. (So if you change the password after the repeatpassword can be equals but you see the error). For me the more transparent solution is force the validation like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77372335/angular-reactive-form-specify-when-to-validate/77373947#77373947)

Answer (score 0):

**I think you are doing password-matching validation all code here It's proper working and you change as per you need**

****html file****

```
<div class="col-4">
      <form [formGroup]="registerForm" #form="ngForm">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group required">
            <div class="services-form">
              <input
                maxlength="50"
                formControlName="Password"
                maxlength="50"
                placeholder="Password"
              />
              <label>Password</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Confirm password -->
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group required">
            <div class="services-form">
              <input
                type="password"
                formControlName="ConfirmPassword"
                autocomplete="off"
                placeholder="Confirm password"
              />
              <label>Confirm password</label>
              <div
                *ngIf="
                  registerForm.get('ConfirmPassword')?.touched &&
                  registerForm.get('ConfirmPassword')?.invalid
                "
                class="input-error"
              >
                {{
                  !registerForm.get('ConfirmPassword')?.value
                    ? 'The confirm
              password field is required.'
                    : 'The password and confirm password
              fields do not match'
                }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

**ts file :**

```
registerForm!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        Password: ['', [Validators.required]],
        ConfirmPassword: ['', Validators.required],
      },
      {
        validator: MustMatch('Password', 'ConfirmPassword'),
      }
    );
  }
```

**must-match.validator.ts**

```
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

// custom validator to check that two fields match
export function MustMatch(controlName: string, matchingControlName: string) {
  return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
    const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];
    const matchingControl = formGroup.controls[matchingControlName];

    if (matchingControl.errors && !matchingControl.errors?.['mustMatch']) {
      // return if another validator has already found an error on the matchingControl
      return;
    }

    // set error on matchingControl if validation fails
    if (control.value !== matchingControl.value) {
      matchingControl.setErrors({ mustMatch: true });
    } else {
      matchingControl.setErrors(null);
    }
  };
}
```

**please check in stackBlitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular13-reactive-form-validation-jqtqvw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmust-match.validator.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts