How to include custom validators and confirm password in an Angular form
I have this interface file:
userslist.ts
export interface Userslist {
    id: number;
    fname: string;
    lname: string;
    email: string;
    pas1: string;
    pas2: string;
}

I am using this interface to get form data including the field First Name, Last Name, email, password and confirm password.
The other two files:
ucreate.component.ts
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Userslist } from '../userslist';
import { UserslistService } from '../userslist.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ucreate',
  templateUrl: './ucreate.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ucreate.component.css']
})
export class UcreateComponent implements OnInit {

  // Declared the 'userForm' variable to store the user entered form data.
  userForm: Userslist = {
    id: 0,
    fname: '',
    lname: '',
    email: '',
    pas1: '',
    pas2: '',
  };


  // Injected the 'UserslistService' and 'Router'.
  constructor(private userlistService: UserslistService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  // Invoking the API call to post the data.
  create(){
    this.userlistService.create(this.userForm)
    .subscribe({
      next:(data) => {
        // On successful saving data to the server, we navigate to the adminhome page.
        this.router.navigate(["/userslist/adminhome"])
      },
      error:(err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    })
  }
}


ucreate.component.html
<div class="container">
    <legend>Create Item</legend>
    <form>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="txtName" class="form-label">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" [(ngModel)] = "userForm.fname" class="form-control" id="txtName" />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="txtName" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lname" [(ngModel)] = "userForm.lname" class="form-control" id="txtName" />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="txtName" class="form-label">e-mail</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" [(ngModel)] = "userForm.email" class="form-control" id="txtName" />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="txtName" class="form-label">Password</label>
        <input type="text" name="pas1" [(ngModel)] = "userForm.pas1" class="form-control" id="txtName" />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="txtName" class="form-label">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="text" name="pas2" [(ngModel)] = "userForm.pas2" class="form-control" id="txtName" />
      </div>
      <button type="button" (click)="create()" class="btn btn-primary">Create Account</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  

How do I include custom validations into the input fields and also how do I show both the passwords are matching or not?

If you make the form a Reactive form, this is fairly trivial. You'd just create the controls, then add validators to the controls, and Angular will handle calling them and setting error flags: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#validating-form-input

You should never have passwords in JavaScript (variables or otherwise). Anyone with a little web browser know how can open the browser console and get the password. All password authentications should take place on the server.

with template driven forms: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78229778/how-to-show-warning-message-for-unmatched-confirm-password/78230056#78230056, with reactive forms:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77372335/angular-reactive-form-specify-when-to-validate/77373947#77373947

They appear to be just doing a frontend check to ensure the two entered passwords match before sending it to the server. That's completely fine to do on the frontend afaik, as long as there's a backend equivalent as well in case the front end checks are bypassed.
